# Why did the Kingsmen allow the candidates for Lancelot to just leave?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-secret-service

Why does this super secret independent spy agency just let the candidates for Lancelot walk away when they wash out of training? I don't even remember any sort of "Never speak of this place or us or we will find you", type of talk when they leave.

Since the candidates know who members are, where their headquarters etc... are, it seems like there would be a little more caution.

Since Charlie recognizes Eggsy at the end of the movie we know there isn't any sort of memory drug used, so what's to stop the wash-outs from being a danger to the society?

Comment: I think it is not too much of a spoiler to say that with the release of Kingsman: The Golden Circle, this question, and a specific detail in the accepted answer become especially poignant.

Comment: @whybird Just watched it last night, but yeah that is exactly what I was thinking when I asked this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a scene right at the beginning of the selection process. The Lancelot candidates are given a body bag and told to write their name and the name of their relative on it. They were told that if they ever told anyone about Kingsmen, they would be placed in the body bag along with their relative.

> - Ladies and gentlemen, my name is Merlin. You are about to embark... on what is probably the most dangerous job interview in the world. One of you, and only one of you, will become the next Lancelot. Can anybody tell me what this is?
> - Body bag, sir.
> - Correct. Charlie, isn't it?
> - Yes, sir.
> - Good. In a moment, you will each collect a body bag. You will write your name on that bag. You will write the details of your next of kin on that bag. **This represents** your acknowledgment of the risks that you are about to face... as well as **your agreement to strict confidentiality. Which, incidentally, if you break, will result in you... and your next of kin... being in that bag.** Is that understood?

This is just before the future Lancelot says that it is classic army scare tactics and noone would actually get hurt.

I guess that the body bag was the ultimate 'Official Secrets Act' that would prevent the rejected candidates from blabbing.

Comment: Can't believe I missed the last part, I was focused on the training aspect, not the confidentiality aspect.